# How to solve ValueError : The given username must be set

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, django, django-users

I am trying to register a user using Python Django. Validations are provided using JavaScript. When a user enter his or her details and click the sign up button, the data will be stored in the database. Suppose if a user click on the sign up button without entering their details, I am getting an error like below.

```
ValueError at /Accounts/CandidateRegister/
The given username must be set
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/Accounts/CandidateRegister/
Django Version: 4.0.2
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
The given username must be set
Exception Location: C:\job\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py, line 137, in _create_user
Python Executable:  C:\job\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.7
Python Path:    
['C:\\job\\jobsite',
 'C:\\Users\\Student\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python39.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Student\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Student\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Student\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39',
 'C:\\job\\venv',
 'C:\\job\\venv\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 19 Apr 2022 10:51:00 +0530
```

I did not understand why this error occurs even if the JavaScript validation provided. Can anyone have any idea to solve this issue.

html

```
<form style="padding:10px 25%;" class="signup-form" id="candidate" name="candidate" method="POST" action="{% url 'candidateregister' %}">
                         {% csrf_token %}
                      <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                          <label for="cafname" style="font: normal normal normal 14px Poppins;">First name</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cafname" name="cafname" placeholder="Your first name" style="font-family:sans-serif;border:2px solid #d4d2d2;">
                          <span id="lfname" class="regval"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                          <label for="calname" style="font: normal normal normal 14px Poppins;">Last name</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="calname" name="calname" placeholder="Your last name" style="font-family:sans-serif;border:2px solid #d4d2d2;">
                          <span id="llname" class="regval"></span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="caemorpn" style="font: normal normal normal 14px Poppins;">Email or Phone number</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="caemorpn" name="caemorpn" placeholder="Enter email or phone number" style="font-family:sans-serif;border:2px solid #d4d2d2;">
                        <span id="lemorpn" class="regval"></span>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="capassword1" style="font: normal normal normal 14px Poppins;">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="capassword1" name="capassword1" placeholder="Enter your password" style="font-family:sans-serif;border:2px solid #d4d2d2;">
                        <span id="lpass" class="regval"></span>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="capassword2" style="font: normal normal normal 14px Poppins;">Confirm Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="capassword2" name="capassword2" placeholder="Confirm your password" style="font-family:sans-serif;border:2px solid #d4d2d2;">
                        <span id="lcpass" class="regval"></span>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="form-check">
                          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="cagridCheck" name="cagridCheck" style="font-family:sans-serif;border:2px solid #d4d2d2;">
                          <label class="form-check-label mt-3" for="cagridCheck" style="font: normal normal normal 14px Poppins;color: #000000;">
                              I agree with the <a href="" style="color:#5A71E1;text-decoration:none;font: normal normal 600 14px Poppins;">Terms and conditions</a>
                          </label><br>
                          <span id="lcheck" class="regval"></span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <input type="hidden"  id="catype" name="catype" value="Candidate"/>
                        {% for msg in messages %}
                            <center>
                                <h4 style="color:red;">{{msg}}</h4>
                            </center>
                        {% endfor %}
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btype" style="background-color:#486DFC;margin-top:5%;font-family:Poppins;" onclick="return candiregister()">SIGN UP</button>
                    </form>
<script src="{% static 'js/register.js' %}"></script>
```

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

def candidateregister(request):
    User = get_user_model()
    if request.method=='POST':
        fname = request.POST.get('cafname')
        lname = request.POST.get('calname')
        email_phone = request.POST.get('caemorpn')
        password1 = request.POST.get('capassword1')
        password2 = request.POST.get('capassword2')
        terms = request.POST.get('cagridCheck')
        type = request.POST.get('catype')
        if terms == 'on':
            terms = True
        else:
            terms = False

        regex = r'\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z|a-z]{2,}\b'

        if (re.fullmatch(regex, email_phone)):
            if (User.objects.filter(email=email_phone).exists()):
                messages.info(request, "Email ID Already Taken")
                return redirect('register')
            user = User.objects.create_user(first_name=fname,last_name=lname,password=password1,terms_and_conditions_confirmed=terms,type=type,email=email_phone,username=email_phone)
            user.save()
            send_action_email(user,request)
            messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'We sent you an Email to verify Your Account...')
            return redirect('login')
        else:
            print(email_phone)
            if (User.objects.filter(phone=email_phone).exists()):
                messages.info(request, "Phone number Already Taken")
                return redirect('register')
            user = User.objects.create_user(first_name=fname, last_name=lname, password=password1,terms_and_conditions_confirmed=terms, type=type, username=email_phone,phone=email_phone)
            user.save()
```

JavaScript

```
function candiregister()
{
    if(document.candidate.cafname.value=="")
    {
        document.getElementById("cafname").style.border= "2px solid Red";
        document.querySelector("#cafname").style.setProperty("--c", "red");
        document.getElementById("lfname").innerHTML="Enter Your First Name";
        return false;
    }
    else
    {

        document.getElementById("lfname").innerHTML="";
    }

    if(document.candidate.calname.value=="")
    {
        document.getElementById("calname").style.border= "2px solid Red";
        document.querySelector("#calname").style.setProperty("--c", "red");
        document.getElementById("llname").innerHTML="Enter Your Last Name";
        return false;
    }
    else
    {

        document.getElementById("llname").innerHTML="";
    }
    if(document.candidate.caemorpn.value=="")
    {
        document.getElementById("caemorpn").style.border= "2px solid Red";
        document.querySelector("#caemorpn").style.setProperty("--c", "red");
        document.getElementById("lemorpn").innerHTML="Enter a Valid Email ID or a Mobile Number(eg:+919999999999)";
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("lemorpn").innerHTML="";
        var mailformat = /^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/;
        var phoneformat = /^((\+){1}91){1}[98765]{1}[0-9]{9}$/;
        if(document.candidate.caemorpn.value.match(mailformat))
            document.getElementById("lemorpn").innerHTML="";
        else if(document.candidate.caemorpn.value.match(phoneformat))
            document.getElementById("lemorpn").innerHTML="";
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("caemorpn").style.border= "2px solid Red";
            document.querySelector("#caemorpn").style.setProperty("--c", "red");
            document.getElementById("lemorpn").innerHTML="Entered Value is not an Email or Mobile Number(eg:+919999999999)";
            return false;
        }
    }
    if(document.candidate.capassword1.value=="")
    {
        document.getElementById("capassword1").style.border= "2px solid Red";
        document.querySelector("#capassword1").style.setProperty("--c", "red");
        document.getElementById("lpass").innerHTML="Enter Password";
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        var pregexp=/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{8,}$/;
        if(document.candidate.capassword1.value.match(pregexp))
               document.getElementById("lpass").innerHTML="";
        else
        {
               document.getElementById("capassword1").style.border= "2px solid Red";
               document.querySelector("#capassword1").style.setProperty("--c", "red");
               document.getElementById("lpass").innerHTML="Contains eight characters,upper&lowercase letter,digit&special characters";
               return false;
        }
    }
    if(document.candidate.capassword2.value=="")
    {
        document.getElementById("capassword2").style.border= "2px solid Red";
        document.querySelector("#capassword2").style.setProperty("--c", "red");
        document.getElementById("lcpass").innerHTML="Enter Password";
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("lcpass").innerHTML="";
        if(document.candidate.capassword1.value!=document.candidate.capassword2.value)
       {
            document.getElementById("capassword2").style.border= "2px solid Red";
            document.querySelector("#capassword2").style.setProperty("--c", "red");
            document.getElementById("lcpass").innerHTML="Password Mismatch";
            return false;
       }
       else

           document.getElementById("lcpass").innerHTML="";
    }
    if(document.getElementById("cagridCheck").checked)
    {
        document.getElementById("lcheck").innerHTML="";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("cagridCheck").style.border= "2px solid Red";
        document.querySelector("#cagridCheck").style.setProperty("--c", "red");
        document.getElementById("lcheck").innerHTML="Please Tick the Checkbox";
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Javascript validation can easily be bypassed, and will also fail if your JS code errors for any reason. You can never rely only on client-side validation, and need to make sure you validate the data server-side before you process it. Django provides a very robust forms framework to do that validation.

Comment: I have to use JavaScript in my project. That is why I have used it. Is there any error in my code.@solarissmoke

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using Javascript - but the fact remains that you cannot rely on client-side validation.

Comment: In ```views.py``` you have ```type``` which you can't use, because it python keyword.

Comment: ok@solarissmoke

Comment: ok. Thanks. I have changed it. But my problem does not solved @shah sawood

Comment: How is ```get_user_model``` implemented, is not cleared so add it to your post.

Comment: ok I will edit the code. Actually `get_user_model` is imported from `django.contrib.auth`@shah sawood

Comment: You have a submit button, and you are sending the form in any case, because there is nothing to stop it. So your javascript doesn't do nothing. Change your function adding the preventDefault() method should fix your problem:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp